# Update tableview row label from another tableview selected row in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have stuck up with an issue where I have a `UITableView` with a label and button in each row when the button is clicked from a particular row it will navigate to the next view and it has `UITableView` with a country list, when selected the country it will popup to the previous view and I want to update the country name with selected row, Could someone guide me how to update it. Below is my code. TIA

FirstViewController.swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
            
    let dict = customData[indexPath.row]  as? NSObject
    cell.lblTitle.text = "Title"
    // cell.lblSubTitle.text = ""
    
    cell.selectedButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}
    
@objc func buttonClick(sender: UIButton){
    let customCell = CountryViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(customCell, animated: true)  
}
```

CountryViewController.swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryCell", for: indexPath) as! CountryTableCell
    
    cell.lblTitle.text = CountryList[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let selectedCountry = CountryList[indexPath.row]
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Update your custom data with selected countryName and reload your table view. Can you explain where you want to display country name after selection?

Comment: if we select the 5th row from FirstViewController and it will redirect to CountryViewController and selected row country name should update to 5th row in FirstViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegation pattern:

```
protocol SelectCountry {
    func countrySelected(withName countryName: String)
}
```

in your FirstViewController.swift conform to that protocol

```
extension FirstViewController: SelectCountry {
func countrySelected(withName countryName: String) {
// Assign country name to your label here
}
```

in your CountryViewController.swift make a variable called delegate/anyName you want

```
var delegate: SelectCountry?
```

in your buttonClick method

```
customCell.delegate = self
```

in your CountryViewController in didSelectRowAt method

```
delegate?.countrySelected(withName: CountryList[indexPath.row])
```

your label will be updated with country name you selected in CountryViewController.

NOTE: Names are just placeholders here you can use your own names for protocol/methods

Comment: how to assign for a specific table row's label. example if we want to update 5th row's label.

Comment: if we select the 5th row from FirstViewController and it will redirect to CountryViewController and selected row country name should update to 5th row in FirstViewController

Comment: @RakshitKumar See you are setting the tag to button in FirstViewController.swift. You just have to get the tag in @objc methods like `index = sender.tag`. when your delegate function triggers there you can fetch `customData[index].title = countryName`.
also you need to reload that row/complete tableView data.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you @GhulamMustafa. I apologize for late response.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Controller:

- "CountrySelectionDelegate" confirm this delegate in your first controller
- Next, Pass/Store your FirstViewController cell selection index.
- Go to your Country Controller, Select country, Pass it through "func selectedCountry(country: String,index: Int) {}" , Update your custom Data/Array.
- Lastly reload your Table view with updated Custom data.

  class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,CountrySelectionDelegate {

  ```
        @IBOutlet weak var yourFirstTable: UITableView!
        var customData = [Details(title: "Title-1", country: ""),Details(title: "Title - 2", country: ""),]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        func selectedCountry(country: String,index: Int) {
            self.customData[index].country = country
            yourFirstTable.reloadData()
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return customData.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableCell
            let custInfo = customData[indexPath.row]
            cell.yourTitleLabel.text = "Title: " + custInfo.title
            cell.yourCountryLabel.text = (custInfo.country.count > 0 ? "Country: \(custInfo.country)" : "Country: ---")
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CountryViewController") as? CountryViewController
            nextVC?.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
            nextVC?.delegate = self
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC!, animated: true)
        }
    }
  ```

2. CountryViewController:

   import UIKit

   ```
    protocol CountrySelectionDelegate {
        func selectedCountry(country: String, index:Int)
    }

    class CountryViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet weak var countryTable: UITableView!

        var selectedIndex: Int = 0
        let countryList = ["India","USA","UK","Nepal","Bangladesh","Pakistan","Bhutan"]
        weak var delegate: CountrySelectionDelegate?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return countryList.count

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell
            cell.countryLabel.text = countryList[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            delegate?.selectedCountry(country: countryList[indexPath.row], index: selectedIndex)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
   ```