# More CollectionViewCells inside one CollectionView to load different data

Tags: ios, swift

This is more of a general question if I could get some insights.
So I have two ViewControllers each with its own ViewModel. Let's call them VC1, VC2, VM1, VM2 respectively.

VC1 has a TableView with multiple cells because I need the content to scroll vertically. VC2 also has a TableView with a list of items.

What I am trying to do now is when I click of any of the VC2's items, I need to transfer that String to VC1 and load data based on its content. That data is loaded through an API. So basically I need to get that String and send it to the API and load the data on VC1. Also, there is an option to add more items in VC1, so I have added a CollectionView inside it (with multiple CollectionViewCells), where each would load data from the chosen String from VC2 (need these to scroll horizontally). So when you run the app at first cell1 from collectionView is shown full screen with some API data, then you scroll horizontally and another cell2 is shown with different data, etc.

This is the general idea of what I need to do, so what I am wondering is how would you go about doing this? Like there is a lot of VC-VM-cell communication and somehow I get lost. What is the best way to get this result that I mentioned above? So far I've managed to get the data to load initially with one result in VC1 (which is not an item from VC2, but a default String from the API), and the list in VC2, but none of the rest (the other collectionViewCells I've added just show empty).

p.s feel free to change anything and everything that I mentioned above,I just need the final result.

Thank you!

Comment: You can communicate between VC's with delegation pattern using protocols. Try to learn how delegation pattern works. for reference please visit the following link and see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013656/update-tableview-row-label-from-another-tableview-selected-row-in-swift/69014087#69014087

Answer (score 0):

You can you delegates, Notifications based on the structure of your code.

***Here's the delegate approach (If VC2 was originally presented from VC1):***

**Create protocol (outside VC1 class)**

```
protocol VC1Delegate: AnyObject {
    func vc1(didSelectItem item: String)
}
```

**Inside VC1**

```
weak var delegate: VC1Delegate?
```

**For tableview of VC1**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellType else { return }
    let selectedText = cell.cellText
    delegate?.vc1(didSelectItem: selectedText)
}
```

I assume YourCellType is the custom cell class you are using which has a property cellText.

**In VC1**
Where you call VC2 (wherever it is):

```
let vc2 = VC2()
vc2.delegate = self
```

Then make VC1 conform to VC2Delegate (do it outside VC1 class):

```
extension VC1: VC2Delegate {
    func vc1(didSelectItem item: String) {
        // Call API, reload table in VC1 or whatever you want
    }
}
```

***Second approach (using notifications):***

**1- Create a notification name**

```
extension Notification.Name {
    public static let vc2ItemNotification = Notification.Name("vc2ItemNotification"
}
```

**2- In VC1: Add the handler:**

```
@objc func didSelectItemInVC2(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let item = notification.userInfo?["item"] as? String else { return }
// Call API, reload table in VC1 or whatever you want
}
```

**3- In VC1:**
Register notification in viewDidLoad.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, #selector(didSelectItemInVC2(_:)), name: .vc2ItemNotification, object: nil)
```

**4- Remove observer**

In VC1, remove Observer. In viewWillDisappear():

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .vc2ItemNotification, object: nil)
```

**5- In VC2:**
Post notification on cell selection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellType else { return }
    let selectedText = cell.cellText
    let message = ["item": selectedText]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .vc2ItemNotification, object: nil, userInfo: message)
}
```